# Explanation regarding limit of function of two independent variables as sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Please help!
If $f(x,y)$ is a real valued function of two variables which is continuous .Then
$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n},y_{n})=f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n},\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n})$, where $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ are any sequences of real numbers whose limits exist.
Is this true in general(Give short proof)?

Comment: No, not without additional assumptions.  Note that you haven't even specified that the limits of $x_n,y_n$ are known to exist (and be finite).

Comment: Thanks for responding.  However the assertation that $f(x,y)$ "has a limit" is not sensible without further context.  Perhaps you mean that $f(x,y)$ is a *continuous* function?

Comment: thanks! have you some kind of proof?

Comment: Sure, now that the Question has been clarified, it is a simple matter to prove using the definition of continuity.  Check your textbook and I'm sure someone will fill any gap in your grasp of how to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = u$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n = v$ be finite (real) limits.

The claim is that for continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, it must happen that:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n,y_n) = f(u,v) $$

This follows pretty quickly from the continuity of $f$ at point $(u,v)$.  Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.  Then there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for any point $(x,y)$ within (Euclidean) distance $\delta$ of $(u,v)$:

$$ |f(x,y)-f(u,v)| \lt \epsilon $$

Now choose integer $N\gt 0$ such that, by the convergence of the sequences, we have for all indexes $n\ge N$ that:

$$ |x_n-u|,|y_n-v| \lt \delta/2 $$

It follows that for all such $n \ge N$, $(x_n,y_n)$ is within distance $\delta$ of $(u,v)$, and thus: $$|f(x_n,y_n)-f(u,v)| \lt \epsilon$$

In other words we can arrange $f(x_n,y_n)$ to be as close to $f(u,v)$ as we wish by requiring $n$ to be "sufficiently large".

Therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n,y_n) = f(u,v)$ as claimed.